# Obter a data atual diretamente pela máquina

Tags: c, datetime

Preciso implementar no meu projeto (sistema para biblioteca) a funcionalidade de obter a data diretamente da máquina. Queria no formato `dia/mês/ano`, para gerar a multa por atraso de entrega de livro automaticamente, porém, só consigo obter desta forma:

[image: Resultado]

É possível obter a data diretamente da máquina no formato que eu falei?

Segue o código:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>


int main(void)
{
    time_t mytime;
    mytime = time(NULL);
    printf(ctime(&mytime));

    return 0;
}
```

https://ideone.com/Sn0DSe

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Você tem que usar a função [`localtime()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/chrono/localtime) para lhe fornecer a data em uma estrutura, depois pode montar como quiser. Tem gente que cria funções prontas para abstrair isso.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

int main(void) {
    time_t mytime;
    mytime = time(NULL);
    struct tm tm = *localtime(&mytime);
    printf("Data: %d/%d/%d/\n", tm.tm_mday, tm.tm_mon + 1, tm.tm_year + 1900);
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/pnrGbp). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/sybvcvyz-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/IO/GetTime.c).

Answer (score 3):

No arquivo de cabeçalho `time.h` existem funções e tipos de dados para manipular informações de tempo e datas.

O tipo de dados `struct tm` define uma estrutura para ser utilizada em funções que trabalham com data e hora.

```
struct tm {
    int tm_sec;   // Indica os segundos de 0 a 59
    int tm_min;   // Indica os minutos de 0 a 59
    int tm_hour;  // Indica as horas de 0 a 24
    int tm_mday:  // Indica os dias do mês de 1 a 31
    int tm_mon;   // Indica os meses do ano de 0 a 11
    int tm_year;  // Indica o ano a partir de 1900
    int tm_wday;  // Indica o dia da semana de 0 (domingo) até 6 (sábado)
    int tm_yday;  // Indica o dia do ano de 1 a 365
    int tm_isdst; // Indica o horário de verão se for diferente de zero
};
```

O tipo de dados `time_t` é usado para representar o tempo de calendário.

A função `localtime()` recebe o tempo em segundos de uma variável do tipo `time_t`, converte para o tempo local, armazena os dados na sua estrutura e retorna um ponteiro para uma `struct` do tipo `tm` com os dados locais.

Exemplo de utilização:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

int main(void)
{
    struct tm *p;
    time_t seconds;

    time(&seconds);
    p = localtime(&seconds);

    printf("Dia do ano: %d\n", p->tm_yday);
    printf("Data: %d/%d/%d\n", p->tm_mday, p->tm_mon + 1, p->tm_year + 1900);
    printf("Hora: %d:%d:%d\n", p->tm_hour, p->tm_min, p->tm_sec);

    printf("\nGeral: %s\n", ctime(&seconds));

    return 0;
}
```